# Can unix socket be used for thrift ruby client?

Tags: ruby, thrift, unix-socket

I'm trying to use thrift, and use ruby as client side.  I'm trying to find documentation for how to initialize a ruby client using the unix domain socket.

Is it possible to use thrift on ruby client and use unix domain socket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Instead of `Thrift::Socket` you use:

```
Thrift::UNIXSocket.new('/path/to/socket')
```

https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/rb/lib/thrift/transport/unix_socket.rb